# Wifi dropping out (limited connectivity) randomly and during high traffic

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, drivers, usb-3, wifi-driver

I built my own PC and everything has been great for over a year until recently when I had to use a wifi adapter. I've tried 2 different brand wifi adapters with the same problem. Basically what happens is that I'll be browsing the web and all of the sudden I'll get limited connectivity.

Troubleshooting the connection in any way (even disabling it) freezes the application working on the problem (e.g., device manager). This also prevents Windows from gracefully rebooting, and I have to hard boot.

The same thing also happens more frequently when I reach download speeds above 1MBps.

What I've tried:

- 2 different wifi adapters
- Updated wifi adapter drivers
- Updated USB 3.0 drivers

If anyone has any ideas as to what may be causing this I'd be very thankful.I'm running windows 8 x64.

Motherboard in question: GA-Z77X-UD3H (rev. 1.0) by Gigabyte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was the problem:

On my mobo there are two kinds of USB 3.0 ports: Intel and Via. I had the wifi adapter plugged into the via USB port and it wasn't working, even after driver updates. So, I plugged it into intel and it seems to work just fine now! Simple fix.

Answer (score 0):

It could certainly be an issue with your WiFi router. Make sure the firmware is up to date. Also, make sure that it isn't located next to a microwave or any other device which could cause interference.

Secondly, install InSSIDer, sort by the RSSI column, and see what networks are around you. If you're using WiFi b or g, you'll want your own WiFi access point to be on channel 1, 6, or 11. Pick the one that appears to be the least-crowded in your area (if there are neighboring WiFi devices on channels 1 and 6, for example, set your WiFi access point to be on channel 11).

Comment: But if it was the router, why would my PC freeze?
The router is clear of any interference, but I live in an apartment complex so there are a billion networks around us. I'm running wireless N though.

Comment: It could be another driver causing a conflict. Fully uninstall the WiFi driver and the USB driver, reboot, reinstall one at a time, and reboot if prompted. This will ensure a clean install. Another thing you may want to install would be the Intel Chipset Software Utility, for chipset drivers.

Comment: Also, make sure your WiFi N is using the 5GHz channel.

Comment: I've done clean driver installs for both USB adapters I've tried, in addition to a chipset driver update.
Wifi is on 5Ghz.

I may have solved it, I'm stress testing now